# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate call adapter for rx.Single<com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody>

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2

I use RxJava1 and Retrofit2 in my project. Around 10% of my users get the following error:

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate call                 
adapter for rx.Single<com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody>.
 Tried:
   * retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory
   * retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory
       at retrofit2.Retrofit.nextCallAdapter(Retrofit.java:237)
       at retrofit2.Retrofit.callAdapter(Retrofit.java:201)
       at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.createCallAdapter(ServiceMethod.java:232)
       at 
retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.build(ServiceMethod.java:160)
       at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:166)
       at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:145)
       at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:913)
...
```

The related code snippets are the following:

```
import rx.Single
```

---

```
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
        .baseUrl(BuildConfig.API_BASE_URL)
        .build()
```

---

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/example")
fun exampleFun(@Field("param") param1: String): Single<ResponseBody>
```

---

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.0.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
```

I've already found similar questions but this is not the same problem.

- Those solutions were about to use `RxJava2CallAdapterFactory` instead
  of `RxJavaCallAdapterFactory` but I use RxJava1.
- The other odd thing
  is that this issue affects only 10% of my users

Comment: why don't you upgrade to rx2?

Comment: Currently it could take a lot of time (and regression). But you are absolutely right, it's on our scope.

Comment: Those look like very old versions. Maybe you have multiple `Retrofit.Builder`s and one of them is missing the adapter setup?

Comment: Yes, I have 3 builders but all of them have adapter setup. The interesting thing is that I just changed `Single` to `Observable` and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I changed `Single` to `Observable` and now it works fine. But if someone knows a better solution, please let me know!

Comment: is there any other better way found?

Comment: No, only moving to RxJava2.

Comment: if someone needs to use Single, it not an answer to replace that with Observable